# Convergence or divergence for $\int _0 ^\infty e^{\sin x} \frac{\sin 2x}{x^\lambda } dx,\lambda>0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Consider the following integral:

> $$\int _0 ^\infty e^{\sin x} \frac{\sin 2x}{x^\lambda } dx,\lambda>0$$

Here's what I did

> First I studied convergence at $\infty$
>   $$|e^{\sin x} \frac{\sin 2x}{x^\lambda }|\le\frac{e}{x^\lambda}
> \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha \frac{e}{x^\lambda}=e\text{, when }\alpha-\lambda=0$$

So, using criterion of convergence by comparing to  $\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ we get that this integral is Absolute Convergent ( so Convergent ) for $\lambda>1$

> Then I studied convergence at $0$
>   $$\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^\alpha e^{\sin{x}}\frac{\sin2x}{x^{\lambda}}=
> \lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin2x}{2x}e^{\sin x}2 x^{\alpha-\lambda+1}=
> 2 \text{, when }\alpha= \lambda-1
> $$

So, using criterion of convergence by comparing to  $\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ we get that for $\lambda-1\ge1\Rightarrow\lambda\ge2$ the integral diverges and for $\lambda \lt2$ it convergerges

> Conclusion: for $\lambda\in(1,2)$ the integral is convergent.

I'm not sure if any of this is correct so I ask you to correct me or use a different way of solving this exercice.  Somebody told me that it can be done with Abel criterion but I'm not very familiar with it
Thank you!

Comment: You've shown it converges absolutely for $\lambda>1$, but this doesn't tell you anything about the convergence for $\lambda\le1$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt But the limits when $\lambda\le 1$ seems to be non-existent because of the $lim_{x\to\infty} \sin{x}$

Comment: The limit of what precisely?

Comment: For convergence at $0$, the limit $e^{\sin x} \frac{\sin 2x}{x^{\lambda}} $ exists only for $\lambda \leq 1$. I am not able to follow what exactly did you do for this case? Also intuitively speaking if $\lambda$ is large, the denominator will go to zero much faster than the numerator so the limit should not exist.

Comment: @sudeep5221 For convergence at $0$ , I used the convergence criterion by comparing to $\frac{1}{(b-x)^{\alpha}}$ where b is $0$ in our case because the limits is at $0$ . I used this formula for determinating convergence and divergence in similar exercices

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I belive that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha e^{\sin{x}}\frac{\sin2x}{x^{\lambda}}$ cannot be determined when $\lambda\le 1$

Comment: @John I think you are mixing up the convergence conditions for $x \to \infty$ and $x \to 0$. When $x \to 0$ comparing it with $|x|^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha >0$ makes little sense as it is diverging. You should compare it with $|x|^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha > 0$. Also to check that note that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} e^{\sin x} \frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{x}}$ exists as it equals $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} 2e^{\sin x} \sqrt{x} \frac{\sin 2x}{2x} = \lim_{x \to 0} 2 \sqrt{x} = 0$.

Comment: You've correctly proved that the integral converges absolutely for $1 < \lambda < 2$. The integral also converges (conditionally) for $0 < \lambda \leq 1$ by Dirichlet's test: $\int_0^\pi e^{\sin x} \sin x \sin' \! x \, dx = 0$ implies that the integral of $e^{\sin x} \sin 2 x$ is uniformly bounded on all finite intervals.

Comment: I guess you can change it to [2e^{sin x} cos x] sinx /x^\lambda, the part in the bracket is bounded, the rest part's integral is possibly convergent since it's alternatively positive and negative and it tends to 0. so perhaps for \lambda >1, the integral is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have

$$\int_{2\pi}^\infty\frac{e^{\sin(x)}\sin(2x)}{x^\lambda}~\mathrm dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n+J_n$$

where

$$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[\frac1{(2\pi n+x)^\lambda}-\frac1{((2n+1)\pi-x)^\lambda}\right]e^{\sin(x)}\sin(2x)~\mathrm dx$$

$$J_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[\frac1{((2n+1)\pi+x)^\lambda}-\frac1{(2(n+1)\pi-x)^\lambda}\right]e^{-\sin(x)}\sin(2x)~\mathrm dx$$

is obtained by splitting the interval $[2\pi n,2\pi(n+1)]$ into four equal subintervals.

Note though that

$$0\le\frac1{(t+x)^\lambda}-\frac1{(t+\pi-x)^\lambda}\le\frac1{t^\lambda}-\frac1{(t+\pi)^\lambda}\le\frac{\pi\lambda}{t^{\lambda+1}}$$

for all $x\in[0,\pi/2]$, since it is decreasing in $x$ and attains a maximum value at $x=0$ and a minimum of $0$ at $x=\pi/2$. The second inequality is deduced from the mean value theorem.

We may then conclude that we have

$$0\le\int_{2\pi}^\infty\frac{e^{\sin(x)}\sin(2x)}{x^\lambda}~\mathrm dx\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\pi\lambda}{(2\pi n)^{\lambda+1}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cosh(\sin(x))\sin(2x)~\mathrm dx$$

and that it certainly converges for $\lambda>0$.

Comment: You have to show that the integral from $2\pi$ to $N$ converges as $N$ goes to infinity, not just for $N$ that are a multiple of ${\pi \over 2}$.

Comment: It's fairly trivial to see that the integral from $N$ to the nearest multiple of $\pi/2$ tends to $0$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: The whole question is fairly trivial.

Comment: Um... okay?${}{}$