# Convergence/Divergence of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin2x}{\sqrt x}e^{\sin x}dx$

Tags: integration

Test the convergence/divergence of this integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin2x}{\sqrt x}e^{\sin x}dx$$

My approach was to split it into two integrals, from 0 to 1 (or any constant really), and from 1 to infinity.

The 0 to 1 part is pretty simple, considering that the function is defined and bounded at all points in that interval.

I'm unsure of how to do the second part, was thinking about using the Dirichlet's test but I can't figure out how to split this function in two.
Also before someone points me to [this more general version of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477619/convergence-or-divergence-for-int-0-infty-e-sin-x-frac-sin-2xx-lamb?noredirect=1),
I'm a first year in college so I'd prefer solutions that use absolute convergence, function comparisons, limit comparison test and obviously Dirichlet's test. That solution was a bit too complicated for me and I expect there be to a much simpler solution considering this is one of our practice questions.

Comment: Why don't you use $1/e\lt e^{\sin x}\le e$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Okay, I tried what you said, writing $\frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt x} e^{\sin x}$ < $\frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt x} e$. Then, I split it into two functions, $h(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ and $g(x) = e \sin 2x$. h is decreasing and tends to zero at infinity, the integral of g is bounded, so by Dirichlet test, the integral is convergent. Have I got this right?

Comment: I don't know about the Dirichlet test, so I can't tell about that. But I can confirm that it's convergent as the the integral on right is a Fresnel integral.

Comment: If $\sin 2x \leq 0$, it's not true that $\frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{x}} e^{\sin x} < \frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{x}} e$.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(2x)\, e^{\sin x}$ does have a relatively simple antiderivative.

Comment: @aschepler Ah yes, got the mistake. Although if I can prove that the absolute value is convergent, I can still prove that the actual value is convergent, so just a correction there. I did notice the antiderivative is simple but I don't think I should be using that here because they expect us to use tests of convergence itself